# Two column Paper , Graph go out side the column

Tags: tikz-pgf, two-column, graphs

I need to draw a graph for my table values. I use xl sheet input data. My article is two column. But Graph go out side the column.I need some expert help to take graph in blue color range.

[image]

This is my code.

```
    .The SSIM results see in below ~\textit{\autoref{tab: c5T1} \nameref{tab: c5T1}}.

%Table
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
 \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{SSIM Values Change with Contrast}
    \label{tab: c5T1}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.47\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline \centering\arraybackslash{\textbf{Method}}  & 
         \centering\arraybackslash{\textbf{0}}  &
          \centering\arraybackslash{\textbf{25}} & 
          \centering\arraybackslash{\textbf{50}} & 
          \centering\arraybackslash{\textbf{100}} \\
        \hline    \centering\arraybackslash{Hard}  &   
        \centering\arraybackslash{0.43576} &  
        \centering\arraybackslash{0.51213} &  
        \centering\arraybackslash{0.63486} &  
        \centering\arraybackslash{0.85057}  \\
        \hline  \centering\arraybackslash{Soft} &  
        \centering\arraybackslash{0.0000} & 
         \centering\arraybackslash{0.16220} & 
          \centering\arraybackslash{0.68675} & 
           \centering\arraybackslash{0.69883}  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Graphe 2 -change with contrastt

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=6cm,
    xlabel={Contrast},
    ylabel={SSIM},   
    ymajorgrids,
    xmajorgrids,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0,
    title = {SSIM value change with Contrast},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    legend pos=south east
    ]
        \addplot table[x=Contrast,y=Hard] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{Hard}
        \addplot table[x=Contrast,y=Soft] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{Soft}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: You may use width=\columnwidth instead of width=\textwidth,

Comment: @LaTeXdraw-com \columnwidth bring it to inside column , but not it more shifted right side. (it is not align with paragraphe above)

Comment: \noindent -fix that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, I have used width=\columnwidth to make sure the graph is as wide as one column in a twocolumn document. Additionally, I have use siunitx in order to avoid repetitive code in the table:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

    .The SSIM results see in below 

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{SSIM Values Change with Contrast}
  \label{tab: c5T1}
  \sisetup{table-format=1.5}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|S|S|S|S|}
    \hline 
    \textbf{Method} & {\textbf{0}} & {\textbf{25}} & {\textbf{50}} & {\textbf{100}} \\
    \hline   
    Hard            &  0.43576     & 0.51213       & 0.63486       & 0.85057        \\
    \hline  
    Soft            &  0.0000      & 0.16220       & 0.68675       & 0.69883        \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Graphe 2 -change with contrastt
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=\columnwidth,
    height=6cm,
    xlabel={Contrast},
    ylabel={SSIM},   
    ymajorgrids,
    xmajorgrids,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0,
    title = {SSIM value change with Contrast},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    legend pos=south east
    ]
        \addplot table[x=Contrast,y=Hard] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{Hard}
        \addplot table[x=Contrast,y=Soft] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{Soft}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: is ti need to put \lipsum , when put that , my total article below that point change

Comment: The command just produces dummy text. Remove it and the lipsum package from your actual document.